# Windows 10 System files bigger than C:\Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, storage

The Windows 10 storage settings say, that my system files (`Settings -> System -> Storage -> C:\ -> System & Reserved -> System files`) have 39.8 GB.
But my `C:\Windows` folder has just 26 GB and the `hiberfil.sys` & `pagefile.sys` have a seperate entry in `System & Reserved`.

What does `System files` report except `C:\Windows`?

I already looked for potential folders in SpaceSniffer and WizTree but I didn't find anything that could fit. I have no Windows.old folder and I already ran Disk cleanup and CCleaner.

Before, 15 GB were used by old NVidia drivers in DriverStore\FileRepository, which I cleaned up with pnputil.exe, but then there were only 1-3 GB more available.

[image: TreeSize Free screenshot]

[image: SpaceSniffer screenshot]

[image: System & Reserved settings]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Is that what you want? @magicandre1981

Comment: @MaxiHuHe04 No; Why would you provide the file free.  Having hundreds of little boxes in an image isn’t helpful

Comment: @Ramhound magicandre1981 said that I should post pictures of TreeSize free

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Both `Program Files` sizes seem normal based on what you have installed.  What directories specifically are you asking about?

Comment: "What does System files report except C:\Windows?" - This question is confusing.  The amount of space used, reported within the Settings UWP application, is limited to the current user at the lowest permission level.

Comment: @Ramhound mainly why the System Files from the settings report 14 GB more than C:\Windows has

Comment: @MaxiHuHe04 - Because the Settings application includes your virtual memory, system restore points, and hibernation file.

Comment: No, that all has a seperate entry in the settings as I wrote

Comment: Run WinDirStat as an Administrator and submit the results.  Failure to run WinDirStat as an Administrator will provide you with invalid results.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't only happen on the boot drive: https://imgur.com/a/qE21x

Comment: Be sure you run the Disk Cleanup  as an Administrator.  I suspect Storage is reporting usage taken up pending updates/old versions of windows/ect since my Storage report is 100% identical to that of WnDirStat

Comment: Yeah, I ran it as Administrator and I checked the updates option

Comment: use TreeSizeFree, not the Pro, I hate this kind of view.

Comment: This is free but I can't screenshot the other view, that would be 1000 screenshots and there you wouldn't really see any more